# Creation of brace sequence not working in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I must create a sequence of numbers using the number of elements that an list has.

`arr1=(1 2 3 4 5 6)`

I thought about the following expression in order to do so, but it is now working.

`echo {0..$(expr ${#arr1[*]} - 1)}
{0..5} # output`

The correct output should be:

`0 1 2 3 4 5`

Could anyone explain me why I do not get the correct values?

Comment: Because as the manual says: `A sequence expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is an integer.`. And you have an integer and a command substitution. And no command substitutions, variables or any other thing gets expanded in that construction.

Comment: Better go create the sequence with `seq 0 ${#arr1[*]} - 1)`

Comment: A pure bash workaround `for ((i=0; i<${#arr1[*]}; i++)); do echo $i; done`

Comment: What you're trying to do works on `zsh` but not in bash because brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an `eval`:

```
$ a=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
$ eval echo {0..$(expr ${#a[*]} - 1)}
0 1 2 3 4 5
```